# Why is Log4J (jul) attempting to MessageFormat a String message from Supplier

Tags: java, logging, lambda, log4j2, java.util.logging

Using Java 1.8 and the Log4J 2.4 JUL adapter (log4j-jul-2.4.jar, log4j-core-2.4.jar, log4j-api-2.4.jar)

```
public class SimpleTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // writing the configuration file on the fly
    try (java.io.PrintStream p = new java.io.PrintStream("./log4j-jul-test.xml")) {
      p.println("<Configuration>");
      p.println("  <Appenders>");
      p.println("    <Console name='Console' target='SYSTEM_OUT'>");
      p.println("      <PatternLayout pattern='JUL: %d %t %-5level %m%n' />");
      p.println("    </Console>");
      p.println("  </Appenders>");
      p.println("  <Loggers>");
      p.println("    <Root level='debug'>");
      p.println("      <AppenderRef ref='Console' />");
      p.println("    </Root>");
      p.println("  </Loggers>");
      p.println("</Configuration>");
    }
    System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "log4j-jul-test.xml");


    // specifying the java.util.logging.LogManager implementation
    // COMMENT THE LINE BELOW TO SEE HOW THE STANDARD JAVA LOGGER REACTS
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager");

    // getting the plain Java logger
    java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("test");

    // works with both standard and JUL loggers
    logger.info(() -> "This 1st line will be logged");  

    // works only with standard Java logger. JUL is attempting to MessageFormat it but shouldn't 
    logger.info(() -> "This 2nd line will {NOT} be logged by JUL");
    // JUL will report that An exception occurred processing Appender Console
    // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: NOT
    //     at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1429)
    //     at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:479)

    // works with both standard and JUL logger
    logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, "This 3rd line will {0} be logged", "successfully");
  }
}
```

The code above is very simple and can be run quickly. Give it a try!

Does anyone know why the Log4J JUL is attempting to *MessageFormat* the *String* supplied when it clearly shouldn't since the standard Java logger doesn't? (and there's now way to pass any parameters anyway)

Note that the method signature is: 
***java.util.logging.Logger***.info(Supplier<***String***>)

Comment: I see no error in the JUL case. It simply prints `INFO: This 2nd line will {NOT} be logged by JUL`.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, I've added an indicator in the code/config file for the Log4J pattern layout, a prefix to the log entry "JUL: ...", can you try again and see if the output has that prefix?

Comment: I was referring to when I comment the `setProperty` line.  The default logger does log it.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, yes, the Java standard implementation does show the 2nd line, the problem stated is that when the Log4J2 JUL LogManager is used, then the same line is not outputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc for java.util.logging.Logger says

> Most of the logger output methods take a "msg" argument. This msg argument may be either a raw value or a localization key. During formatting, if the logger has (or inherits) a localization ResourceBundle and if the ResourceBundle has a mapping for the msg string, then the msg string is replaced by the localized value. Otherwise the original msg string is used. Typically, formatters use java.text.MessageFormat style formatting to format parameters, so for example a format string "{0} {1}" would format two parameters as strings.

Because of this Log4j anticipates that code written for jul expects this and so converts the supplied String to a [MessageFormatMessage](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/MessageFormatMessage.html). However, in looking at the Formatters supplied by the JDK, none of them actually seem to support MessageFormat formatting. This would be worth discussing on the Log4j users list.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion rgoers. I have reported this as a _bug_ in the Apache Log4J 2 JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1158

Comment: 'However, in looking at the Formatters supplied by the JDK, none of them actually seem to support MessageFormat formatting.'  The support is in the [j.u.l.Formatter.formatMessage](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/logging/Formatter.java) method.  The JDK formatters extend that base class so all formatters that use formatMessage support MessageFormat formatting.